# C# commandline decompiler

Tags: c#, decompiler

I'm looking to decompile a lot of assemblies into C#. I found several tools that do a visual decompile. However I was wondering if there is a tool that can do decompiling from the command line (similar to `ildasm /OUT`).

The motivation is that there are 100+ of assemblies and I don't want to open each one and save as an `.cs` file. [.NET Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) seems to have a batch load of assemblies, but it doesn't have a batch save. So I was thinking of writing a script that goes through each assembly and decompiles it using a command line command.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to have a program that generates the C# code for an assembly, [Jon Gallant](http://blog.jongallant.com/2011/11/decompile-dll-using-c.html) recently had a blog post about doing this using JustDecompile from Telerik.  There are a couple of assemblies that you link to and then you can control the generation of the code without a UI.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need is this open source decompiler called dnSpy -> https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy

includes a command line tool:

```
Examples:
  dnSpy.Console.exe -o C:\out\path C:\some\path
      Decompiles all .NET files in the above directory and saves files to C:\out\path
  dnSpy.Console.exe -o C:\out\path -r C:\some\path
      Decompiles all .NET files in the above directory and all sub directories
  dnSpy.Console.exe -o C:\out\path C:\some\path\*.dll
      Decompiles all *.dll .NET files in the above directory and saves files to C:\out\path
  dnSpy.Console.exe --md 0x06000123 file.dll
      Decompiles the member with token 0x06000123
  dnSpy.Console.exe -t system.int32 --gac-file "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0"
      Decompiles System.Int32 from mscorlib
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as a continuation of the answer from above, dnSpy seems to be discontinued and crashed for me when I tried to use it (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72938117/dnspy-console-does-not-show-any-output/75494360#75494360)).

Maybe consider using [dnSpyEx](https://github.com/dnSpyEx), which worked like a charm.